# How to copy multi-arch docker images to a different container registry?

Tags: docker, buildx

There's a well-known approach to have docker images copied from one container registry to another. In case the original registry is dockerhub, the typical workflow would be something like this:

```
docker pull <image:tag>
docker tag <image:tag> <new-reg-url/uid/image:tag>
docker push <new-reg-url/uid/image:tag>
```

Now, how do you the above when dealing with images with multi-architecture layers?

As per the information in this [link](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/multi-arch/), you can rely on `buildx` to construct multi-arch images, and while doing that, you can also upload those to whichever repo you wish, but **how** do i do this without having to first build the images?

Looks like `buildx` cli has unnecessarily (?) coupled the uploading process with the building one. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

While the `docker pull ...; docker tag ...; docker push ...` syntax is the easy way to move images between registries, it has a couple drawbacks. First, as you've seen, is that it dereferences a multi-platform image to a single platform. And the second is that it pulls all layers to the docker engine even if the remote registry already has those layers, making it a bad method for ephemeral CI workers that would always need to pull every layer.

To do this, I prefer talking directly to the registry servers rather than the docker engine itself. You don't need the functionality from the engine to run the images, all you need is the registry API. Docker has documented the original [registry API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/) and OCI recently went 1.0 on the [distribution-spec](https://github.com/opencontainers/distribution-spec/) which should get us some standardization.

There's a variety of tooling based on those specs, from the docker engine itself and containerd, to skopeo, google's crane, and I've also been working on [regclient](https://github.com/regclient/regclient). Doing this with regclient's regctl command looks like:

```
regctl image copy <source_image:tag> <target_image:tag>
```

And the result is the various layers, image config, manifests, and multi-platform manifest list will be copied between registries, but only for the layers that don't already exist on the target registry.

Comment: `regctl` works like a charm, it does exactly what i needed, and even more (as you indicated), as it's smart enough to detect pre-existing layers and prevent unnecessary i/o. I hope some day these new features are incorporated into the high-level container runtimes (e.g. docker, podman, etc) to save us needing to learn yet-another tool. Thanks a lot @BMitch!

Comment: What if you cannot communicate directly with the target registry? I have to go through a bastion host . so I backup to a tar file, upload the tart file to a host the remote registry has access to, from the registry server I can download the tar file, load the image, and then push it to the target registry.  It's convoluted thanks to security requirements.

Comment: @majorgear specifically with regctl it can output to an OCI Layout which is a filesystem equivalent of a repository. Either with `regctl image copy` where the source or target is `ocidir://$dir` or `regctl image export` and `regctl image import` to use a tgz file instead.

Comment: My security team denied my request to install regctl , so what I did was build each image with architecture-specific tags in order to manage each image individually. I learned that the local registry does't support multi arch images, which was the root of my problem.

Answer (score 13):

### 2022 docker built-in solution

It is now possible to perform the copy using the built-in `docker buildx imagetools create` command and specifying a `--tag` argument.

```bash
OLD_TAG=registry.example.com/namespaced/repository/example-image:old-tag
NEW_TAG=registry.example.com/namespaced/repository/example-image:new-tag

docker buildx imagetools create --tag "$NEW_TAG" "$OLD_TAG"
```

[Reference documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_imagetools_create/)

Answer (score 2):

There is an open-source tool [skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo).

Quote:

> Copying an image from and to various storage mechanisms. For example
> you can copy images from one registry to another, without requiring
> privilege.

To just copy an image from one registry to another (from official [examples](https://github.com/containers/skopeo/blob/main/docs/skopeo-copy.1.md#examples)):

```bash
skopeo copy --all docker://docker.io/skopeo/stable:latest docker://new-reg-url/skopeo:latest
```