Is it possible to download content of a remote repository and upload it to a local repo?
I have a remote Docker repository that I can use to pull images like this:
docker image pull docker.mydomain.tld/alpine:latest

I attempted to download the contents of this remote repository using the JFrog CLI and upload them to another repository in my private network (which has no internet access). The upload appears successful, and when I compare the repositories in the GUI, they seem identical.
However, when I try to pull some images from the local repository, the operation occasionally fails. Not all images fail, but some do.
I investigated the issue by comparing the exported files from the remote repository with those exported from the local repository and found some differences. For example:
Directory structure:
/tmp/export
├── docker-local
│   └── alpine
│       ├── latest
│       │   ├── manifest.json
│       │   ├── sha256__38a8310d387e375e0ec6fabe047a9149e8eb214073db9f461fee6251fd936a75
│       │   └── sha256__4048db5d36726e313ab8f7ffccf2362a34cba69e4cdd49119713483a68641fce
│       └── _uploads
│           └── manifest-sha256__fa7042902b0e812e73bbee26a6918a6138ccf6d7ecf1746e1488c0bd76cf1f34.json
└── docker-remote
    └── library
        └── alpine
            ├── latest
            │   └── list.manifest.json
            └── sha256__2c43f33bd1502ec7818bce9eea60e062d04eeadc4aa31cad9dabecb1e48b647b
                ├── manifest.json
                ├── sha256__38a8310d387e375e0ec6fabe047a9149e8eb214073db9f461fee6251fd936a75
                └── sha256__4048db5d36726e313ab8f7ffccf2362a34cba69e4cdd49119713483a68641fce

Additionally, I noticed that the manifest.json files differ in content. For example:

In the remote repository export, the mediaType field is:
"mediaType": "application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json"

In the local repository export, the mediaType field is:
"mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json"


My Question
What could be causing these differences, and why do some images fail to download from the local repository? Is there a specific process or tool required to ensure a consistent and functional transfer of images between repositories?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I believe there are multiple near duplicates: several relevant ones include https://stackoverflow.com/q/68567983/596285, https://stackoverflow.com/q/75321144/596285, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/49976188/596285 (note the comment and alternate answer). Specifically with regctl you'll want to copy to/from ocidir://${dirname}:${tag} for the air-gap.

I use jfrog cli, whereas all questions you pointed out are about building docker image or pull/push docker images! I didn't get my answer out from those QAs.

I can't say what might be wrong with the jfrog cli. But I believe the linked answers do help with the question "Is there a specific process or tool required to ensure a consistent and functional transfer of images between repositories?" Each of the linked questions is about copying images between registries, which doesn't need to be jfrog specific.

Thank you, @BMitch. I understand your point. Currently, I'm using JFrog Artifactory and prefer to utilize their official utility for exporting/importing repositories. However, I will refer back to those Q&As if I fail to resolve the JFrog CLI problems

I appreciate your works and your answer @BMitch , finally I used regctl to achieve my goal. and I saved my scripts in a github repo for others as an example. Fill free to ask me or open a pull request yourself if you want any change in its README or somewhere link: https://github.com/mahyard/registry-sync

oh I forgot to note that I was failed to use Jfrog Cli's exported oci and decided to use regctl for both exporting and importing images

Glad to hear it helped. I'm looking to add a website for the project in the future where blog posts and user contributions like this would be easier to add.
